# What's the most efficient way to move a large number of items between collections in DSpace CRIS?

Tags: dspace

I need to move a large quantity of Items (~ 1200) from one Collection to another. My current idea is to use the export and import tools, but I have not been successful. I have not been able to update, or even add new items, using these tools. My process has been as follows:

- Get a list of the items from the old collection (**collection-export**), and then
- Modify the xls file following the instructions in the manual (dspace-cris-2022.02.00 pag. 93-94, create an ACTION column, etc.)
- Import the items into the new collection (**bulk-import**)

Unfortunately, I have not been successful. The process finishes with no issues, but no change is made. The logs show the following message when trying to ADD a single item.

```
2023-05-29 04:35:28.096 INFO bulk-import - 89 @ The script has started
2023-05-29 04:35:28.114 INFO bulk-import - 89 @ Start reading all the metadata group rows
2023-05-29 04:35:28.114 INFO bulk-import - 89 @ Found 0 metadata groups to process
2023-05-29 04:35:28.115 INFO bulk-import - 89 @ Found 1 items to process
2023-05-29 04:35:28.260 INFO bulk-import - 89 @ The script has completed
```

There are some answers related to similar issues, but they are for old versions of DSpace CRIS. I am using "**dspace-cris-2022.02.00**" and "**dspace-angular-dspace-cris-2022.02**".

I would like to know:

- Is this the correct way to move items between collections? How can this be done using these tools? The items can be moved individually, but that would take a long time to complete
- If this is not the correct way, then what is it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer you, how I do it with **DSpace CRIS 2023.01** for metadata only. If there are bitstreams to move then Simple Archive Format (SAF) import/export may be an option, since otherwise you must manually take care of copying the corresponding files (bitstreams).
By the way, `metadata-import` and `metadata-export` writing/reading csv-files are DSpace tools (DSpace only, without CRIS) and seem prone to malfunctions, such as adding metadata instead of replacing, or creating items instead of refering.

Your choice is correct, as `collection-export` and `bulk-import` are specific DSpace CRIS tools.
One known bug of version 2023.01 is that `bulk-import` must be run as administrator from the UI and not the command line, since on CLI there is no option yet to set the executing eperson (in terms of DSpace CRIS).
As first test I recommend to export a collection, make slight changes to the xls-file and import this file. If that works, then I would prepare the real data. My personal preference is one xls-file only for adding (ADD) and another only for updating existing items (UPDATE). For sake of completeness, here is the link to the [documentation](https://github.com/4Science/dspace-angular/releases/download/dspace-cris-2023.01.00/dspace-cris-2023.01.00.pdf).

Just one idea about your test run, one item was found. Maybe it is on the workspace (UI - *My Dspace*) and requires manual actions. If so, then you might find what was missing in the table.